# recording object state for serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to find a way to record the state of the different objects on the canvas (image, shape, select box) so it can all be serialized into XML or JSON. I've tried placing each object into a global array:

```
var shapeState = { //Example of a shape being recorded
                            number:increment,
                            id:thisCanvas,
                            type:'shape',
                            kind:shapeKind,
                            cheight:canvasHeight,
                            cwidth:canvasWidth,
                            height:shapeHeight,
                            width:shapeWidth,
                            color:shapeColor,
                            x:xPos,
                            y:yPos
                        }

                        totalState.push(shapeState); //State of shape data has been stored in global array
```

But this only works if the shape (or other object) is static. If, for example, i move the element (after clicking the 'move' button), how can i update the `xPos` property? The shape object would have already been placed inside the array and unidentifiable by name. Say there are 100+ shapes in the global array, how would i be able to find a specific one to update? Please help.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
var AllShapeStates = {};

function Shape() {
    var SerializedState = {},
        number,
        thisCanvas,
        etc;
    AllShapeStates[UNIQUE_IDENTIFYING_ATTRIBUTE] = SerializedState;
    //Shape Business

    this.updateState = function(){
        SerializedState.number = number;
        SerializedState.id = thisCanvas;
        //etc
    }
}
```

In this model, when a `Shape` is instantiated, it adds a reference to its `SerializedState` into the global `AllShapestates` var; Whenever the `Shape` updates it's state, it should call `updateState`,  which updates its `SerializedState` object;

Comment: @Shad--i dont understand how your solution would last beyond the life of one viewing. if a user decided to exit the page to visit a different site and then came back, the shapes would be gone. 

I dont know much about ASP.NET, but maybe the `[_VIEWSTATE]` variable could be used here?

Comment: @codeninja Your question is tagged as JavaScript, I don't understand where `.NET` comes into it. In my answer, an accurate State is always accessible inside of `AllShapeStates` for any given shape.